# Is there any way to use a threads's tasks queue in Java for backoff retry?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

how to do a implement correctly an "Exponential backoff" on java server?

I have this code:

A ParallelStream calls this methods (multi threaded) :

```
private void concurrentlyUpdateCachedLine(String lineName, ConcurrentLineUpdate lineUpdate) {
try {
for (long delayMs = 1; ; delayMs = Math.max(delayMs *2, 100)) {
final IdentifiableValue retrievedIdentifiable = retrieveIdentifiable(lineName);
Line retrievedLine = (Line) retrievedIdentifiable.getValue();

if (retrievedLine == null) {
create(lineName);
continue;
}

lineUpdate.doUpdate(retrievedLine);

if (memCache.putIfUntouched(lineName, retrievedIdentifiable, retrievedLine)) {
break;
}
Thread.sleep(delayMs);
}
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
System.out.println("Error when caching line");
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

When i wrote an Exponential backoff on android or ios,

i used threads' queue

```
    if shouldRetryToGetGCMToken() {
        let nextRetryTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, nextRetryInterval())
        dispatch_after(nextRetryTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
            self.receivedApnsToken(self.application, deviceApnsToken: self.appDelegate.apnsDeviceToken!)
        }
    } else {
        print("Out of retries to get GCM token. Permanent failure.")
    }
```

Is there any way to use a queue in Java?

Answer (score 0):

This is a base class to handle requests and resend them using exponential back-off.

In the source code you will find:

1. The class BackOffStrategy.java
2. The unit testBackOffStrategyTest.java

Basically, this code gives you an idea of how to implement an exponential back-off strategy to resend a request when there is an unsuccessful call. You can configure the number of retries and the default waiting time. In the unit test you will see some examples of how to use it. You can make it more complex according your development requirements (handle custom exceptions, wait more time, add some custom logic, etc).

This was my base class for the implementation of:

1. A backend webservice with retry logic
2. XMPP Connection Server for FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging)

https://github.com/carlosCharz/ExponentialBackOff

And also I've created a video in youtube where I explain what it does.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8Dq99MDHtY

Hope you find it useful.